# PHP - Infinite loop while read a stream after try to do a git push with proc_open

Tags: php, windows, git

i'm stuck for two days now on the same issue.

I'm trying to create a commit and push it to my remote repository using shell commands throw with PHP.
I'm able to do a **git add** or a **git commit** but not a **git push**. When I try to use `stream_get_contents` on the pipe opened by `proc_open('git push [...]');`, it does an infinite loop and I can't see any result or errors ...

I tried to put a timeout or set non-blocking mode but nothing change in the execution. I also tried to print the user with `whoami` and I get '*nt authority\system*' but I don't know what to do with that.

After looking for many PHP forums and libraries on GitHub or GitHub API, I didn't find any solution who works for me (maybe I did them wrong?).

### Here somes links who I have looked:

- [Running git pull from a php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370975/running-git-pull-from-a-php-script) (I'm on Windows OS not linux)
- https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-shellcommand (Infinite loop too)
- https://github.com/kbjr/Git.php (Infinite loop too)
- https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#contents (Can upload or modify a file in a repo but not an entiere commit)
- https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-shellcommand/issues/20#issuecomment-521752406 (Infos ...)

### My config:

- **Git** (v2.24.1.windows.2)
- **PHP** (v7.4.0)
- **Wamp Server** (v3.2.0)
- **Windows** (v10.0.18363.1082)

### Here's my code

```
$descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout
    2 => array("file", "C:/wamp64/www/myproject/error-output.txt", "a") // stderr
);
$pipes = array();

$process = proc_open("git push origin mybranch", $descriptorspec, $pipes);

/* This part doesn't seem to work on Windows */
stream_set_blocking($pipes[0], 0);
stream_set_blocking($pipes[1], 0);
stream_set_timeout($pipes[0], 5);
stream_set_timeout($pipes[1], 5);

if (is_resource($process)) {
    $data = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]); // <- Infinite loop here, but why ??
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    proc_close($process);
    echo $data;
}
```

Please someone help me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few weeks later, I finally found the source of the problem. It was not proc_open but stream_get_contents that blocked me. When I done a git push, my system ask for me to enter my git's username and password but executed by PHP, I don't have a terminal instance to put my values so stream_get_contents still wait to an entry who never comes.
I used `git config` to set my repo credentials and then it works !